# Scapy layer for MPEG2-TS, with conditionalField for adaptation

Tags: python, scapy

I try to create a MPEG2-TS layer for scapy.

I need to "add" and parse additional fields based on the adaptation field.

Here is my code:

```
_adapt_type = {
0x0 : 'Reserved',
0x1 : 'Payload only',
0x2 : 'Adaptation only',
0x3 : 'Adaptation and payload',
}

class MPEG2_TS(Packet):
    name = "MPEG2-TS"
    fields_desc=[

            ByteEnumField('sync_byte', 0x47, _sync_type),
            BitField('trans_err',0x0, 1),
            # Transport Error Indicator (TEI) if set to 1 decoder ignore packet

            BitField('start_ind',0x0, 1),
            BitField('trans_pri',0x0, 1),
            XBitField('pid', 0xA, 13),
            BitEnumField('trans_scramb', 0x0, 2, _scramble_type),
            BitEnumField('adapt_ctrl', 0x0, 2, _adapt_type),
            BitField('cont_count', 0x0, 4),
            ]
```

I need to parse additional data if the adapt_ctrl is set to:

```
0x1 : 'Payload only',
0x2 : 'Adaptation only',
0x3 : 'Adaptation and payload'
```

How can I create a condition to be able to parse it base on the result of this field ?
If the "Payload Only" bit is set, there is no adaptation fields after the header, thus we didn't need to parse it.
If the "Adaptation and payload" is set, I need to parse the adaptation fields using the following structure:

```
_adapt_fields = [

            # Number of bytes in the adaptation field immediately following this byte
            ByteField('ada_len', 0x0),

            # Set to 1 if current TS packet is in a discontinuity state with respect to either the continuity counter or the program clock reference
            BitField('dis', 0x0, 1),

            # Set to 1 if the PES packet in this TS packet starts a video/audio sequence
            BitField('ran_acc', 0x0, 1),

            # 1 = higher priority
            BitField('ES_str_pri', 0x0, 1),

            # Set to 1 if adaptation field contains a PCR field
            BitField('PCR_fla', 0x0, 1),                

            # Set to 1 if adaptation field contains an OPCR field
            BitField('OPCR_fla', 0x0, 1),

            # Set to 1 if adaptation field contains a splice countdown field
            BitField('spl_fla', 0x0, 1),

            # Set to 1 if adaptation field contains private data bytes
            BitField('trs_pri_dat_fla', 0x0, 1),

            # Set to 1 if adaptation field contains an extension
            BitField('ada_ext_fla', 0x0, 1),                

            # variable Depends on flags
            # BitField('ada_ext_fla', 0x0, 1),              
            # PCR   33+6+9      Program clock reference, stored in 6 octets in big-endian as 33 bits base, 6 bits padding, 9 bits extension.
            # OPCR  33+6+9      Original Program clock reference. Helps when one TS is copied into another
            # Splice countdown  8       Indicates how many TS packets from this one a splicing point occurs (may be negative)
            # Stuffing bytes    variable        
            ]
```

I tried with some ConditionalField but without luck till now.
Thanks for help.